# How to add routes to navigator in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have just gotten into react native and I have zero mobile experience, so I have a couple of questions. Mainly regarding the navigator.

I have an initial stack, something like this (psuedo code)

```
routes = [
    {scene: 1}, {scene: 2}, {scene: 3}
]
```

and I swipe between them.

Now, let's say I want to push a new scene from scene one (nested navigation?). I end up having

```
routes = [
    {scene: 1}, {scene: 4 (pushed scene)}
]
```

And this is where  I'm stuck. What is the correct way of handling this? Should I reset the stack and lose the transition or is there a way how i could push the new scene as the last scene and end up with something like

```
routes = [
    {scene: 1}, {scene: 2}, {scene: 3}, {scene: 4}
]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just want to clarify on what you're trying to accomplish: you want to start at scene 1, push to scene 4, but when you hit back you want it to go to scenes 3 and 2 before reaching back to 1?

Comment: @MattAft I have a sort of a swipeable tab navigation in the root. When I navigate to a new scene (let's say secene 4), the tabs at the bottom still exist and I want to navigate through them. So essentially, visually speaking I have three scenes side by side that I can stack views on top. I hope this helped

Comment: What kind of navigator component are you using? You should search for react native tabbed navigation. Have you checked [this](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-3-adding-tabs-28a2c57356b6#.pgsow1i5e)

Comment: @milkersarac Uh, thank you for the link. I did not know about this. But I ended up nesting navigators and that worked out great for me. But using navigator for tabbed navigation is really awful as I'm learning now, so I'll take a stab at experimental navigation. Thanks!

Comment: The best practice is always what is work for you and what you are good at, however you should always keep learning and try the new stuff :) Good luck, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I strongly recommend you to read the official doc of React Native navigator (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html). There are many functions to do with the routes.

In your example, if you just want to add a new view from scene1, you can call this in scene1

```
this.props.navigator.push(Routes.scene4);
```

And in scene4, you can call this to go back to scene1 and this won't affect your current stack with scene2 and scene3

```
this.props.navigator.pop()
```

Alright, let's say you want to add scene4 in scene 3, and want to click the back button to go back to scene1 (The very first scene). How can you do it? 
You can call the following function

```
this.props.navigator.popToTop()
```

Which redirects you to the very top of the stack - scene1.

There're also many other functions that are quite usefull: popToRoute(ANY_ROUTE_BEFORE_THIS), jumpTo(ROUTE_YOU_WANT) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow `react-native` tutorial on add navigation. I'll list some of the steps here,

```
  npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack
  npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

  cd ios
  pod install
  cd ..
```

After that (which is for ios), then you can replace your `App` with

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Home from './pages/Home'


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App
```